# Android Studio If statement with || and && operator

Tags: java, android, if-statement, is-empty

I'm creating an application which updates users on the score of a football match either in real time or as a final result. At least one score must be inputted in order for the `TextView` to be updated and the relevant score to be displayed. I'm checking that at least 1 of a pair of `EditText` fields is not empty using the following code:

```
if(!(et_current.getText().toString().isEmpty())||(!(et_final.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
&& (!(et_current2.getText().toString().isEmpty())||(!(et_final2.getText().toString().isEmpty()))){
     if(!(et_final.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
              tv_final.setText(et_final.getText().toString());
     else
              tv_current.setText(et_current.getText().toString());

     if(!(et_final2.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
              tv_final2.setText(et_final2.getText().toString());
     else
              tv_current2.setText(et_current2.getText().toString());
}
```

I want to be able to set the correct `TextView` so I have another if statement inside the original if statement to see ensure the correct score is being updated.

When I run the code, I do not seem to be getting past the first if statement. Am I using the correct format or is there an better way to complete these checks?

Thanks!

Comment: Two comments: Add `null` checks on those strings and also use brackets.

Comment: Try to use `== ""` instead of `isEmpty()`, maybe it will solve something

Comment: @itay_421 `== ""` won't work. Use `.equals ("")`, instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you do not need to add `null` checks, those Strings may be empty but not null. Also `isEmpty()` works fine

Comment: One more tip is that you don't have to cast to `String` to determine if it's empty. Use `TextUtils.isEmpty(tv.getText())` or `tv.getText().length() == 0` or even better `TextUtils.getTrimmedLength(tv.getText()) == 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For readabilities sake, get some variables going

```
    boolean currentEmpty = et_current.getText().toString().isEmpty();
    boolean current2Empty = et_current2.getText().toString().isEmpty();
    boolean finalEmpty = et_final.getText().toString().isEmpty();
    boolean final2Empty = et_final2.getText().toString().isEmpty();
```

And then your code can be much cleaner. Something like

```
    if( (!currentEmpty || !finalEmpty) || (!current2Empty || !final2Empty)) {

        if(finalEmpty) {
            tv_current.setText(et_current.getText());
        }
        else {
            tv_final.setText(et_final.getText());
        }

        if(final2Empty) {
            tv_current2.setText(et_current2.getText());
        }
        else {
            tv_final2.setText(et_final2.getText());
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if that is completely correct as the requirement is not entirely clear to me, but it should atleast be a good start to follow what's going on.